# Infinite scrolling bar chart without re-rendering of data using d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on building a dynamically scrolling bar chart with the following required behavior:

1. The initial view of chart should contain a specified(a constant) amount of observations from the complete data with a scroll bar below.
2. On scrolling to almost the end of bar, some new data should be included automatically into the chart without re-rendering. In other words, new data should be added into the chart rather than re-rendering the chart on whole data
3. This process should continue on further scrolling giving a feel of infinite scrolling bar chart.
4. y-axis scales should remain constant throughout the whole process.

I am fairly new to d3.js and have basic understanding on how to build a scrolling bar chart and build an infinite scrolling list (using jquery). However i am not able to figure out how to :

1. How to update the x-axis scale in alignment with the new loading data.
2. Will d3.js be efficient for this (considering i need to input ~ 10-100k data points) or is there any better possible solution?

Also,any existing projects/demos which showcase the above functionality are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add new data to the chart without re-rendering the whole data again

This is very easy to do in d3. See for example this [bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/RandomEtc/cff3610e7dd47bef2d01)

> How to update the x-axis scale in alignment with the new loading data.

In the above example the x axis updates automatically.

The trick to this part is to trigger the scrolling event once you reach the bottom.

> Will d3.js be efficient for this (considering i need to input large amounts of data on scrolling) or is there any better possible solution?

The limits are on the browser more than on d3.js. I don't know how much do you consider 'large amounts of data' so I cannot help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                                          By large amounts i mean around 10-100k datapoints in my chart. Will the scrolling work smoothly for this amount of data?                                       Or is there any different approach (other than d3.js) that i should go for?

Comment: Also i'll be loading around 1000 data points initially and add further 1000 points to the chart every time the scroll event triggers.

Comment: 100k datapoints might be too much, but it's not a d3 limitation, its a browser one. If you cannot aggregate this data I suggest consider using canvas https://bl.ocks.org/pbeshai/65420c8d722cdbb0600b276c3adcc6e8